# Dynamic Job Definitions using Control M REST API (Version 9.0.19)

Tags: control-m

How do I create a Dynamic job definition and run it for one time execution only (like on-demand job) using control-m REST API Automation?

Every time I pass a JSON file it is being considered as a Static job definition is getting saved to my workspace which I am trying to avoid.

I'm trying to understand how control m interprets the job definition as either static or dynamic? We are trying to migrate off ctmcreate and start using REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Control-M PM here, we're working on an official API replacement for ctmcreate, which is currently scheduled for release with the upcoming version (9.0.21.200), subject to any last minute changes. If you need an immediate solution, you can use the CTM RUN request to run your job definitions without first deploying them. Here's a link to the documentation for the RUN service (note the version): https://documents.bmc.com/supportu/API/Monthly/en-US/Documentation/API_Services_RunService.htm

If you open an Request For Enhancement (RFE) the Control-M team will contact you when the feature is ready for Beta testing.